# Getting Grails to read external dataSource config and load appropriate JDBC drivers

Tags: tomcat, grails, config

My Grails app runs fine in Tomcat when the (MySQL) `dataSource` is defined in `DataSource.groovy`. But when using an external config file I get `ClassNotFoundException`s for the MySQL drivers from Tomcat. No special War dependencies are set up either.

I am probably missing something obvious, but cant seem to identify it. Tried moving the MySQL connector to the `CATALINA_HOME/lib`, but that doesn't do it.

Any thoughts or help is greatly appreciated!

```
....
//loading external config  
def extConfig = System.properties.getProperty("${appName}-config.location");  
grails.config.locations = [ "file:${extConfig}/${appName}-config.properties"]  
//config file contents.  
dataSource.pooled = true  
dataSource.dbCreate = "create-drop"  
dataSource.driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"  
dataSource.username = "root"  
dataSource.password = "ttech"  
dataSource.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/registration"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our projects we have an external properties file for configuration and we use it to set the datasource configuration as well, in our case we use PostgresSQL and we use the BuildConfig.groovy to include the jar file for the driver, when the WAR is generated Grails dependency management system puts the jar in WEB-INF/lib and that has worked just fine for us, no need to put in the Tomcat lib folder.

In your settings I see that you are not specifying the dialect for the datasource, you might want to check that in your external file too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, that does work. But if the JDBC jar is in the shared container classpath, shouldn't Grails pick it up too? I should be able make my app db-agnostic right?

Comment: I see what you are saying, I haven't tried it though. However, it seems it should work with no problem per this thread http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/More-grails-apps-under-tomcat-and-same-jdbc-driver-td1368048.html

Comment: I externalize the datasource config as a properties file; once I changed it to a .groovy-formatted file, it worked. Not sure what was amiss. Makes me a little uneasy.

Comment: I think I know what your problem was with the .properties file. When Grails loads a .properties files it uses the Properties class from Java, this class manages all values as String so you don't need to define values with "", like for example dataSource.driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" should be just dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, so probably the app was trying to find a class named "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" instead of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: Thank you. The incorrect properties file format was the problem. I am completely embarrassed at that oversight!!